# Unexpected errors in Collapse accordion with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, bootstrapping

I have developed web page on Ruby on Rails with Collapse bootstrap.
With Haml I have tried as follows.
But there are some unexpected errors.

```
.accordion-group
    .accordion-heading
      %according-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target"=>"#{heading}"}
        = link_to heading, "#{heading}"
    .accordion-body.collapse.in{:id => "#{heading}"}
      .accordion-inner
        -items.each do |item|
        %li{ :class => (params[:controller] == item[:controller] ? "active" : "") }
          = link_to item[:path] do
            - if item[:data_icon]
              %span{ :class => "nav-icon", :data => {"icon" => "#{item[:data_icon]}".html_safe}}
              %span{ :class => "nav-text"}
                = "#{item[:name]}"
            - else
              = "#{item[:name]}"
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
...:Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer....
 
This is a error message

Answer (score 0):

It seems your indentation is incorrect, can you check line below `items.each`
that should be inside the loop.

```
.accordion-group
  .accordion-heading
    %according-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target"=>"#{heading}"}
      = link_to heading, "#{heading}"
  .accordion-body.collapse.in{:id => "#{heading}"}
    .accordion-inner
      - items.each do |item|
        %li{ :class => (params[:controller] == item[:controller] ? "active" : "") }
          = link_to item[:path] do
            - if item[:data_icon]
              %span{ :class => "nav-icon", :data => {"icon" => "#{item[:data_icon]}".html_safe}}
              %span{ :class => "nav-text"}
                = "#{item[:name]}"
            - else
              = "#{item[:name]}"
```

Comment: You seem right, but my issue is different from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed code as follows.
The reason was heading includes space and special character like '&'.
So I replaced them with underscore.
After that it is working.

```
.panel-group{:id=>"accordion"}
  - groups.each do |heading, items|
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      %h4.panel-title
        %a.accordion-toggle{"data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-parent"=>"#accordion",:href=>"#"+"#{heading}".gsub(/\W/,'_')}
          = raw heading
    .panel-collapse.collapse{:id=>"#{heading}".gsub(/\W/,'_')}
      .panel-body
        %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
          - items.each do |item|
            %li{:class => (params[:controller] == item[:controller] ? "active" : "") }
              = link_to item[:path] do
                - if item[:data_icon]
                  %span{ :class => "nav-icon", :data => {"icon" => "#{item[:data_icon]}".html_safe}}
                  %span{ :class => "nav-text"}
                  = "#{item[:name]}"
                - else
                  = "#{item[:name]}"
```

Comment: I have implemented like this.